# Refreshing Bokeh DataTable through Selection of Plots

Tags: python, datatable, callback, widget, bokeh

I am trying to update Bokeh DataTable by selecting a plot.Not sure why it's not getting updated?In the code below,source_devon is ColumnDataSource for the plot- I wanted Datatable to get updated when we select a particular portion.Currently DataTable is created(initialization),but it doesn't changes on selection

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import layout,row
from bokeh.models import CDSView,HoverTool,GroupFilter,ColumnDataSource,Button,Select,TextInput,Slider,DataTable,TableColumn,DateFormatter,LinearAxis,Range1d,CustomJS,Rect
from bokeh.plotting import figure,output_file,show
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from bokeh.client import push_session
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np



TOOLS='pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,tap,save,lasso_select,xbox_select'

# Select widget
ccy_options = ['AUDUSD', 'USDJPY']
menu = Select(options=['AUDUSD','USDJPY'], value='AUDUSD')
slider = Slider(start=-1000, end=10000, step=1000, value=-1000, title='Volume Cutoff')


# Function to get Order/Trade/Price Datasets
def get_combined_dataset(src,name):
df = src[(src.CCYPAIR == name)].copy()
return ColumnDataSource(data=df)

# Function to Make Plots
def make_plot(source_order):
x  = 'DATE'
y  = 'PRICE'
y1 = 'Volume'
size = 10
alpha = 0.5
hover = HoverTool(
tooltips = [
    ('OrderId', '@ORDER_ID_108'),
    ('Volume', '@Volume'),
    ('Price', '@PRICE')
    ]
)
view1 = CDSView(source=source_order, filters=[GroupFilter(column_name='TYPE',group='ORDER'),GroupFilter(column_name='SIDE',group='B')])
view2 = CDSView(source=source_order, filters=[GroupFilter(column_name='TYPE',group='ORDER'),GroupFilter(column_name='SIDE',group='S')])
view3 = CDSView(source=source_order, filters=[GroupFilter(column_name='TYPE',group='TRADE'),GroupFilter(column_name='SIDE',group='B')])
view4 = CDSView(source=source_order, filters=[GroupFilter(column_name='TYPE',group='TRADE'),GroupFilter(column_name='SIDE',group='S')])
view5 = CDSView(source=source_order, filters=[GroupFilter(column_name='TYPE',group='DevonTrade')])
view6 = CDSView(source=source_order, filters=[GroupFilter(column_name='TYPE',group='Prices')])
plot2 = figure(plot_width=1000, plot_height=300, tools=[hover, TOOLS], 
   title='Agg. Position Snapshot for Devon',
   x_axis_label='Date', y_axis_label='Price',x_axis_type="datetime")

plot = figure(plot_width=1000,    plot_height=300,tools=TOOLS,x_axis_type="datetime",title='Order/Execution Snapshot with Price Levels')
plot.circle(x=x,y=y,source=source_order,view=view1,alpha=0.6,color='blue')
plot.circle(x=x,y=y,source=source_order,view=view2,alpha=0.6,color='red')
plot.triangle(x=x,y=y,source=source_order,view=view3,alpha=0.6,color='blue')
plot.triangle(x=x,y=y,source=source_order,view=view4,alpha=0.6,color='red')
plot.line(x=x,y=y,source=source_order,view=view6,color='green')
plot2.line(x=x,y=y1,source=source_order,view=view5,color='blue')
plot.legend.location = 'top_left'
return plot,plot2

def make_table(source):
columns = [
TableColumn(field='DATE', title="DATE", formatter=DateFormatter()),
TableColumn(field='CCYPAIR', title="CCYPAIR"),
    TableColumn(field='SIDE', title="SIDE"),
    TableColumn(field='PRICE', title="PRICE"),
    TableColumn(field='TYPE', title="TYPE"),
    TableColumn(field='Volume', title="Volume"),
    TableColumn(field='ORDER_ID_108', title="ORDERID"),
]
data_table = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns, width=1000, height=200)
return data_table
def update_plot(attrname, old, new):
newccy = menu.value
newvalue = slider.value
src_data_table = get_combined_dataset(Combined,newccy)
DisplayData.data.update(src_data_table.data)


def update_plot(attrname, old, new):
newccy = menu.value
newvalue = slider.value
src_data_table = get_combined_dataset(Combined,newccy)
DisplayData.data.update(src_data_table.data)


def selection_change(attrname, old, new):
data =  get_all_dataset(Combined,menu.value)
selected = DisplayData.selected['1d']['indices']
if selected:
   data  = data.iloc[selected, :]
   update_datatable(data)

def update_datatable(data):
src_data_table = get_combined_dataset(data,menu.value)
s2.data.update(src_data_table.data)

# Input Files    
date_today = datetime.now()
days = pd.date_range(date_today, date_today + timedelta(5), freq='D')
Combined1 = {'DATE': days,
 'CCYPAIR': ['USDJPY', 'USDJPY', 'USDJPY','USDJPY', 'USDJPY', 'USDJPY'],
 'SIDE' : ['B', 'B', 'B','B', 'B', 'B'],
 'PRICE': [100.00, 200.00, 300.00,100.00, 200.00, 300.00],
 'TYPE' : ['ORDER', 'ORDER', 'ORDER','DevonTrade', 'DevonTrade', 'DevonTrade'],
 'Volume': [100, 200, 300, 100, 200, 300],
 'ORDER_ID_108':  [111,222,333,111,222,333]
   }
Combined = pd.DataFrame(Combined1)


DisplayData =  get_combined_dataset(Combined,menu.value)
plot,plot2 =  make_plot(DisplayData)
menu.on_change('value', update_plot)
plot.x_range = plot2.x_range

s2 = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(DATE=[],CCYPAIR=[],SIDE=[],PRICE=[],TYPE=[],Volume=[],ORDER_ID_108=[]))

columns = [
    TableColumn(field='DATE', title="DATE", formatter=DateFormatter()),
    TableColumn(field='CCYPAIR', title="CCYPAIR"),
    TableColumn(field='SIDE', title="SIDE"),
    TableColumn(field='PRICE', title="PRICE"),
    TableColumn(field='TYPE', title="TYPE"),
    TableColumn(field='Volume', title="Volume"),
    TableColumn(field='ORDER_ID_108', title="ORDER_ID_108")
]
data_table = DataTable(source=s2,columns=columns,width=1000, height=200)



layout = layout([menu],
            [plot],
            [plot2],
            [data_table])
curdoc().add_root(layout)

DisplayData.on_change('selected', selection_change)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main issue is that the source you are updating does not have the same fields as the source containing the original data. In your callback you are trying to access d2['DATES'] and d2['PRICES'], however you defined the fields as 'x' and 'y'. See below code which has corrected this. I also defined the plotting ranges of the second plot so the data will appear.

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import layout,row
from bokeh.models import HoverTool,ColumnDataSource,Button,Select,TextInput,Slider,DataTable,TableColumn,DateFormatter,LinearAxis,Range1d,CustomJS,Rect
from bokeh.plotting import figure,output_file,show
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from bokeh.client import push_session
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


TOOLS='pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,tap,save,lasso_select,xbox_select'

# Select widget
menu = Select(options=['AUDUSD','USDJPY'], value='USDJPY')

# Function to get Order/Trade/Price Datasets
def get_order_dataset(src,name):
    df = src[(src.CCYPAIR == name) & (src.TYPE == 'ORDER') & (src.SIDE == 'B')].copy()
    return ColumnDataSource(data=df)

# Function to Make Plots
def make_plot(source_order):
    x  = 'DATE'
    y  = 'PRICE'
    size = 10
    alpha = 0.5
    hover = HoverTool(
    tooltips = [
        ('OrderId', '@ORDER_ID_108'),
        ('Volume', '@Volume'),
        ('Price', '@PRICE')
        ]
    )

    plot = figure(plot_width=1000, plot_height=300, tools=[hover, TOOLS], 
       title='Order/Execution Snapshot with Price Levels',
       x_axis_label='Date', y_axis_label='Price',x_axis_type="datetime",active_drag="xbox_select")

    plot.circle(x=x, y=y, size=size, alpha=alpha, color='blue',
            legend='Orders', source=source_order,selection_color="orange")
    plot.legend.location = 'top_left'
    return plot

def update_plot(attrname, old, new):
    newccy = menu.value
    src_order = get_order_dataset(Combined,newccy)
    source_order.data.update(src_order.data)


date_today = datetime.now()
days = pd.date_range(date_today, date_today + timedelta(2), freq='D')
Combined1 = {'DATE': days,
     'CCYPAIR': ['USDJPY', 'USDJPY', 'USDJPY'],
     'SIDE' : ['B', 'B', 'B'],
     'PRICE': [100.00, 200.00, 300.00],
     'TYPE' : ['ORDER', 'ORDER', 'ORDER'],
     'Volume': [100, 200, 300],
     'ORDER_ID_108':  [111,222,333]
       }
Combined = pd.DataFrame(Combined1)

source_order = get_order_dataset(Combined,menu.value)

plot =  make_plot(source_order)
menu.on_change('value', update_plot)

s2 = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(DATE=[], PRICE=[]))
p2 = figure(plot_width=1000, plot_height=400,
    tools="", title="Watch Here",x_axis_type="datetime", y_range=(90,310),x_range=(days[0],days[-1]))
p2.circle('DATE', 'PRICE', source=s2, alpha=0.6, size=10)

source_order.callback = CustomJS(args=dict(s2=s2), code="""
var inds = cb_obj.selected['1d'].indices;
console.log(inds)
var d1 = cb_obj.data;
var d2 = s2.data;
d2['DATE'] = []
d2['PRICE'] = []
for (i = 0; i < inds.length; i++) {
    d2['DATE'].push(d1['DATE'][inds[i]])
    d2['PRICE'].push(d1['PRICE'][inds[i]])
}
s2.change.emit();""")

layout = layout([menu],
        [plot],
        [p2])
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

Comment: If the dependent plot generated after selection is needed in DataTable format(where we display all columns like CCYPAIR,SIDE,PRICE,TYPE,Volume,ORDER_ID_108 in the selected timerange),how can we do it?

Comment: Try create a datatable, and use the same source which is then uploaded in the javascript callback. The callback can update the necessary columns, which should propagate through into the table in a similar fashion as in your example code

Comment: HI,I have updated my original code.I see that when I select,nothing comes up in DataTable and selection hangs.Essesntially I would like to see all values from dataframe in the selected timerange!!!

Comment: I have updated code which is partially working now - the problem though I see is that error msg comes up Errorhandling message Message 'PATCH-DOC':DeserializationError("Seq(Any) expected a list or None , got '0')  Secondly shouldnt this code display plot.line items as well.I only see plot.circle and plot.triangle items getting displayed in datatable.

Answer (score 0):

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import layout,row
from bokeh.models import  CDSView,HoverTool,GroupFilter,ColumnDataSource,Button,Select,TextInput,Slider,DataTable,TableColumn,DateFormatter,LinearAxis,Range1d,CustomJS,Rect
from bokeh.plotting import figure,output_file,show
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from bokeh.client import push_session
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np



TOOLS='pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,tap,save,lasso_select,xbox_select'

# Select widget
ccy_options = ['AUDUSD', 'USDJPY']
menu = Select(options=['AUDUSD','USDJPY'], value='AUDUSD')
slider = Slider(start=-1000, end=10000, step=1000, value=-1000,     title='Volume Cutoff')


# Function to get Order/Trade/Price Datasets
def get_combined_dataset(src,name):
df = src[(src.CCYPAIR == name)].copy()
return ColumnDataSource(data=df)

# Function to Make Plots
def make_plot(source_order):
x  = 'DATE'
y  = 'PRICE'
y1 = 'Volume'
size = 10
alpha = 0.5
hover = HoverTool(
tooltips = [
('OrderId', '@ORDER_ID_108'),
('Volume', '@Volume'),
('Price', '@PRICE')
]
)
view1 = CDSView(source=source_order, filters=   [GroupFilter(column_name='TYPE',group='ORDER'),GroupFilter(column_name='SIDE',group='B')])
view2 = CDSView(source=source_order, filters=[GroupFilter(column_name='TYPE',group='ORDER'),GroupFilter(column_name='SIDE',group='S')])
view3 = CDSView(source=source_order, filters=[GroupFilter(column_name='TYPE',group='TRADE'),GroupFilter(column_name='SIDE',group='B')])
view4 = CDSView(source=source_order, filters=[GroupFilter(column_name='TYPE',group='TRADE'),GroupFilter(column_name='SIDE',group='S')])
view5 = CDSView(source=source_order, filters=[GroupFilter(column_name='TYPE',group='DevonTrade')])
view6 = CDSView(source=source_order, filters=[GroupFilter(column_name='TYPE',group='Prices')])
plot2 = figure(plot_width=1000, plot_height=300, tools=[hover, TOOLS],
```

title='Agg. Position Snapshot for Devon',
   x_axis_label='Date', y_axis_label='Price',x_axis_type="datetime")

```
plot = figure(plot_width=1000,    plot_height=300,tools=TOOLS,x_axis_type="datetime",title='Order/Execution Snapshot with Price Levels')
plot.circle(x=x,y=y,source=source_order,view=view1,alpha=0.6,color='blue')
plot.circle(x=x,y=y,source=source_order,view=view2,alpha=0.6,color='red')
plot.triangle(x=x,y=y,source=source_order,view=view3,alpha=0.6,color='blue')
plot.triangle(x=x,y=y,source=source_order,view=view4,alpha=0.6,color='red')
plot.line(x=x,y=y,source=source_order,view=view6,color='green')
plot2.line(x=x,y=y1,source=source_order,view=view5,color='blue')
plot.legend.location = 'top_left'
return plot,plot2

def make_table(source):
columns = [
TableColumn(field='DATE', title="DATE", formatter=DateFormatter()),
TableColumn(field='CCYPAIR', title="CCYPAIR"),
TableColumn(field='SIDE', title="SIDE"),
TableColumn(field='PRICE', title="PRICE"),
TableColumn(field='TYPE', title="TYPE"),
TableColumn(field='Volume', title="Volume"),
TableColumn(field='ORDER_ID_108', title="ORDERID"),
]
data_table = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns, width=1000, height=200)
return data_table
def update_plot(attrname, old, new):
newccy = menu.value
newvalue = slider.value
src_data_table = get_combined_dataset(Combined,newccy)
DisplayData.data.update(src_data_table.data)


def update_plot(attrname, old, new):
newccy = menu.value
newvalue = slider.value
src_data_table = get_combined_dataset(Combined,newccy)
DisplayData.data.update(src_data_table.data)


def selection_change(attrname, old, new):
data =  get_all_dataset(Combined,menu.value)
selected = DisplayData.selected['1d']['indices']
if selected:
 data  = data.iloc[selected, :]
update_datatable(data)

def update_datatable(data):
src_data_table = get_combined_dataset(data,menu.value)
s2.data.update(src_data_table.data)

# Input Files    
date_today = datetime.now()
days = pd.date_range(date_today, date_today + timedelta(5), freq='D')
Combined1 = {'DATE': days,
'CCYPAIR': ['USDJPY', 'USDJPY', 'USDJPY','USDJPY', 'USDJPY', 'USDJPY'],
'SIDE' : ['B', 'B', 'B','B', 'B', 'B'],
'PRICE': [100.00, 200.00, 300.00,100.00, 200.00, 300.00],
'TYPE' : ['ORDER', 'ORDER', 'ORDER','DevonTrade', 'DevonTrade', 'DevonTrade'],
 'Volume': [100, 200, 300, 100, 200, 300],
 'ORDER_ID_108':  [111,222,333,111,222,333]
  }
 Combined = pd.DataFrame(Combined1)


 DisplayData =  get_combined_dataset(Combined,menu.value)
 plot,plot2 =  make_plot(DisplayData)
 menu.on_change('value', update_plot)
 plot.x_range = plot2.x_range

 s2 = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(DATE=[],CCYPAIR=[],SIDE=[],PRICE=[],TYPE= [],Volume=[],ORDER_ID_108=[]))

 columns = [
 TableColumn(field='DATE', title="DATE", formatter=DateFormatter()),
 TableColumn(field='CCYPAIR', title="CCYPAIR"),
 TableColumn(field='SIDE', title="SIDE"),
 TableColumn(field='PRICE', title="PRICE"),
 TableColumn(field='TYPE', title="TYPE"),
 TableColumn(field='Volume', title="Volume"),
 TableColumn(field='ORDER_ID_108', title="ORDER_ID_108")
 ]
 data_table = DataTable(source=s2,columns=columns,width=1000, height=200)



 layout = layout([menu],
                 [plot],
                 [plot2],
                 [data_table])
 curdoc().add_root(layout)

 DisplayData.on_change('selected', selection_change)
```

Comment: Currently Bokeh has a issue - only clicks can be selected.Lines can't be via Box Select Tool. https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwia8bmhx-LYAhUKLMAKHaKiDJYQFggvMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgroups.google.com%2Fa%2Fcontinuum.io%2Fd%2Ftopic%2Fbokeh%2FzE9dkPlcmQI&usg=AOvVaw0UqPqe-mqkV1j8_hXrYTvd